# Firebase real-time database check with two value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I need to check a record already exist or not with two value to avoide duplicate records. My database structure is like below:

```
movielist
         movies
              -M5RwyBsC1cwTzX4LU-A
               backdropPath: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5BwqwxMEjeF..."
               genres: "Science Fiction, Drama"
               imDBid: "tt2935510"
               posterPath: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xBHvZcjRiWy..."
               releaseDate: "2019"
               title: "Ad Astra"
               userId: "SZ7zU6toVcSSablbnZif8n4MTIb2"
               voteAverage: "6.6"
               watched: false
```

So I need to check a user with userId and the movie with imDBid if exist or not before added. If there is a more efficient way to do this you can suggest any type of structure of db too.

updated code(edited):

```
    final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("movies");

    ...
    FutureBuilder(
           future: getData(_name),
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
    .....

             floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder(
                          future: dbRef.orderByChild("imDBid").equalTo(snapshot.data.imdbId).once(),
                          builder: (context, snapshots) {
                          return FloatingActionButton(
                             backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.4),
                             onPressed: (){
                             Movies movies = new Movies(snapshot.data.imdbId, snapshot.data.originalTitle, snapshot.data.posterPath, snapshot.data.backdropPath, snapshot.data.releaseDate, snapshot.data.title, snapshot.data.voteAverage, snapshot.data.genres, false, userId);
                            _database.reference().child("movies").push().set(movies.toJson());},

                           child: Icon(snapshots.data.value != null ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border )
      )
   }
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using firebase realtime database, then the only way to do this, is to combine both attribute into one.

So you will have the following:

```
movies
  randomid
    userId_imbdId  : valueId_valueId
```

Then you can check if `userId_imbdId` is equal to the userId_movieid

Comment: That's practical way to make unique key but I use the data in my ui, maybe I keep my user_id as it is and revise the imdbId value as you mention so this value can be use some string action with split or .replaceAll(userId, "") something. Just one more question, how can avoid duplicate record with this query?

Comment: U can add this attribute and keep the other two also. To prevent duplicate you need to use a query example: `orderByChild("userId_imbdId").equalTo(valueId_valueId)` then if u get data it means it exists, if you don't get data then it doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks but it never get null I think, I tried ( print(FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().orderByChild("imDBid").equalTo("any id") != null) and it returns true even id is added or not. I think I need to research for that a bit more. My main problem is I have a homepage is listing all movies from db belong to userid but when I go to detailpage that is build itself from another future function and I cannot connect both somehow. I tried to make a sub futurebuilder to my "add to" button to control it's icon shape and onpressed action but couldn't achive yet. So different then local db logic.

Comment: https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/02/16/using-firebase-queries-in-flutter/  you need to use `once()` which returns a future

Comment: I am reading the article it's really informative thanks, if i am not bother you, can you check edited part in my question. As I understand when I do that if snapshot.data.imdbid which came from first future isn't equal to any record of database "imDBid" child then snapshots(of second future) must be null but when I try that like updated code as I add to my question icon never change with the if else situation. Just trying to understand the logic that's I use changing icon, if I can change icon I can change onpressed action according to this data so that would avoid duplicate records.

Comment: Ignore my last comment I figured out it, I just need to orederbychild and check the snapshot.data.value is null or not. Now I can progress with this, thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this ‏https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data, do it the same use if(snapshot.hasData){//show icon and use CircularProgressIndicator so it will appear before the data is fetched

Answer (score 0):

You can chain 2 where clauses together.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("movies)
     .where("userId", isEqualTo: "Some user Id")
     .where("imDBid isEqualTo: "Some imDBid")
```

Comment: I am using firebase auth and real-time database so I don't implement firestore in anywhere and I tried that with FirebaseDatabase.instance but it doesn't have collection or where I think.